# Is there a connection between these "Once Upon a Time In..." titled films?

Tags: title, once-upon-a-time-in-america, once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

Sergio Leone directed two similarly titled films:

- [*Once Upon a Time in the West* (1968)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064116/)
- [*Once Upon a Time in America* (1984)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087843/)

**What is the connection between the films?** Is there a reason the film titles are so similar? Is there an in-universe connection? Did Sergio Leone ever mention a reason for the similar titles? Are they meant to be part of an anthology? (I realize that's a lot of questions so I've emboldened the root question I'm asking.)

Comment: What I do think to have heard is that he actually wanted to do *America* first and has always wanted to do that project. But before going about this he was convinced that he "owed" Hollywood a proper Western or something like that. For whatever that's worth for answering the actual question.

Comment: Good question - ill be keeping my eye out for an answer - as you said, I always assumed it was just to stylise them as parts of anthology but I have not seen either of them in nearly a decade (and have only watched them twice each) so I cannot even begin to recall if any details suggest a shared universe.

Comment: Not by Leone but there's whole lot of movies named 'Once upon a time...' , see here in [imdb](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls076447648/)

Comment: @Vishwa Interesting..didn't know about the others !! Will have to watch them sometime..

Comment: The connection is the interest and collaboration between author Harry Golberg and Sergio Leone (discussed in Christopher Frayling's 'Segio Leone: Something to Do with Death'.

Comment: @wcullen I know Harry Goldberg was the author of the novel "The Hoods" which was adapted into the film "One Upon a Time in America", but what does that have to do with "Once Upon a Time in The West"?

Comment: @Vishwa I've noticed that trend as well, in fact that was what my question was going to be about originally, but I figured it was a little too broad.

Comment: Leone read Goldberg's book while filming 'Once Upon a Time in the West'. When the two finally got together he asked Goldberg to help him better understand America. 

This became Leone's 'Once Upon A Time in America'. 

So the connection, at least in this regard, is through the discussions and collaboration between the two over several decades beginning with one film (about the American West) and ending with the other (American gangsters).

This is the connection I see from having read Frayling's book. There maybe others.

Comment: @wcullen seems like you could probably flesh that out into a decent answer.

Comment: I'll put something in the answer section if I'm very sure it's accurate and answers the question.

Otherwise, I tend to prefer to leave 'things to think about' (or 'musings with a purpose'..?) in the comment sections.

Although I do think this sheds light on the question, I'm not sure this "answers" the question. I hope, if nothing else, it was interesting... :-) PS: If you're really interested in Leone's work Frayling's book is good read.

Comment: I'd definitely be interested to hear more about what the book says about this.

Comment: Why not include Once Upon a Time in Mexico to your question? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285823/ It's not leone, but the pattern is clearly there as well.

Comment: And also, Once Upon A Time In Mexico, and some others.

Answer (score 2):

After the Dollars trilogy Leone wanted to do what eventually became known as the "America Trilogy" Once Upon A Time in the West, Once Upon a Time in the Revolution (also known as Die You Sucker), and Once Upon a Time in America are all part of that trilogy.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064116/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv

Answer (score 1):

Your core question was already answered by @Rosie. But i will take a few lines to reply to

> Is there a reason the film titles are so similar?

The phrase *Once upon a time ...* is a very common pattern when starting a fairy tale. So by naming his movie with this prefix, Sergio Leone emphasizes that he is telling a story in the sense of a fairy tale that you might have been read to as a kid. Just in a different format and with horses and guns instead of kings and dwarves.

It might also be worth noting that the English title might not have been the original name, but the Italian one.